# "Object doesn't support this action" error when navigate to new component in IE

Tags: angularjs, angular, internet-explorer, typescript2.0

I got the error message when I stayed at a component and navigate to another one. The error will not show if I stay at that component and refresh. It happen in some components. I tried to create new component with nothing in the content, it's still happen if I navigate to this component. The error message is showed in a none-stop way.

I'm using Angular 2 final. It's just happen in IE (Using IE11). Here is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^2.2.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.1.25",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-pagination": "^1.0.1",
    "ng2-translate": "4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "strip-bom": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-insert-lines": "0.0.4",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.13",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.7.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "typings": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
```

And here is my polyfill.ts:

```
import 'core-js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

import 'ts-helpers';

if (process.env.ENV === 'prod') { // Production
    // @Todo: will be defined
} else {
    // Development
    Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;
    require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
}
```

See the error:

[image]

It did not happen before. So I can't find out the root cause and the solutions. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the root cause. A function is called in none-stop way from the other library even in the pages have no objects which it need. No objects is provided, it caused the problem. I fixed it by adding condition to stop calling the function when in the pages with no provided object.